# Rendering a dynamic data list in React-Table cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-table

I am trying to dynamically render data in a bulleted list inside of a table cell using the react-table npm package. I was able to render a bulleted list, but it returns all of the 'Route' arrays within the JSON structure, whereas I just want to return the corresponding Route data to each cell. I have provided my current code and the data JSON structure as well.

```
render() {
  const data = this.state.testData;
  const exportData = this.state.csvData;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          ref={(r)=>this.reactTable=r}
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Subhead",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Label",
                  accessor: "Label",
                  width: 140,
                  className: 'bold_label'
                },
                {
                  Header: "Channel Number",
                  headerClassName: 'small_th', // Set the classname of the `th` element of the column
                  accessor: "Channel_Number",
                  width: 55,
                  className: 'center_col '
                },
                {
                  Header: "FEC Type",
                  accessor: "FEC_Type",
                  width: 65,
                  className: 'center_col'
                },
                {
                  Header: "Latency",
                  accessor: "Latency",
                  width: 75,
                  className: 'center_col'
                },
                {
                  Header: "Utilized Bandwidth Gbps",
                  accessor: "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps",
                  className: 'center_col'
                },
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: "Subhead",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Wavelength Distance",
                  accessor: "Wavelength_Distance",
                  className: 'center_col',
                  width: 75,
                },
                {
                  Header: "Channel Capacity Gbps",
                  accessor: "Channel_Capacity_Gbps",
                },
                {
                  Header: "Channel Capacity ODU",
                  accessor: "Channel_Capacity_ODU",
                },
                {
                  Header: "Free Bandwith Gbps",
                  accessor: "Free_Bandwith_Gbps",
                },
                {
                  Header: "Free Bandwith ODU",
                  accessor: "Free_Bandwith_ODU",
                },
                {
                  Header: "OSNR",
                  accessor: "OSNR",
                  width: 45,
                },
                {
                  Header: "OSNR Threshold",
                  accessor: "OSNR_Threshold"
                },
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: "Subhead",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Pre FEC BER",
                  accessor: "Pre_FEC_BER",
                  className: 'center_col'
                },
                {
                  Header: "Route",
                  accessor: () => data.map(data => {
                    return (
                      <ul>
                        <li>{data.Route}</li>
                      </ul>
                    )
                  }),
                  id: "Route",
                  width: 200,
                },
              ]
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 1,
      "FEC_Type": "",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "9-7-B-OSN6800_3:TPE_3-14-1_PTP::9-9-C-OSN6800_3:TPE_3-14-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1529.16
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 80,
      "FEC_Type": "",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "9-1-lab-A-OSN6800_1:TPE_1-8-1_PTP::9-9-C-OSN6800_1:TPE_1-8-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 10.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94b48b-670f-493a-9b55-c6a9b56b0288",
        "5c94b485-6c76-4877-9ae2-d6a34e1062ff"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1560.61
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 15,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC2",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "M96HD01-MUE01-U16_0:TPE_0-1-2_PTP::M96HD01-A2E01-U16_0:TPE_0-1-2_PTP",
      "Latency": 70.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": 0.0,
      "Route": [
        "5c94b489-c799-4aae-a707-67003f658dea",
        "5c94b488-4e22-48d7-9932-c154cf89ce25",
        "5c94b487-943a-40e0-ad61-1b6da491f90b",
        "5c94b488-411e-46e1-b234-dbc9d6b7ff42",
        "5c94b489-0d88-49a2-9f42-36345b64d1fe",
        "5c94b487-35f7-4500-875e-43ed88c74e51"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 8,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 6.666666666666667,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1534.64
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": null,
      "FEC_Type": "",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "9-7-B-OSN6800_3:TPE_3-2-1_PTP::9-9-C-OSN6800_3:TPE_3-2-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": null
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 74,
      "FEC_Type": "",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "9-9-C-OSN6800_1:TPE_1-11-4_PTP::9-7-B-OSN6800_1:TPE_1-8-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 10.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1558.17
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 10,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC2",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "M96HD01-A2E01-U32_0:TPE_0-1-1_PTP::M96HD01-M3Q01-U32_0:TPE_0-3-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": 0.0,
      "Route": [
        "5c94b486-2c47-49ef-9305-c478b501f2e2",
        "5c94b487-5bb2-45cc-9bdf-1736e6f276c1",
        "5c94b486-37c6-4feb-b260-bad91ca53952",
        "5c94b48a-7618-4fd9-b0b5-8c5377223240"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 33,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 27.5,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1532.68
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 80,
      "FEC_Type": "",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "9-1-lab-A-OSN6800_1:TPE_1-11-1_PTP::9-9-C-OSN6800_1:TPE_1-11-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 8,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 6.666666666666667,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1560.61
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": null,
      "FEC_Type": "",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "9-9-C-OSN6800_3:TPE_3-14-4_PTP::9-7-B-OSN6800_3:TPE_3-14-4_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": null
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 40,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC2",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "M96HD01-MUE01-U16_0:TPE_0-1-1_PTP::M96HD01-A2E01-U16_0:TPE_0-1-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": 0.0,
      "Route": [
        "5c94b488-95e5-4f83-8dad-deffcee3a027",
        "5c94b489-86a2-444a-85d7-e54a8d7c68fd"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1544.53
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 11,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC2",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "M96HD01-M3Q01-U32_0:TPE_0-3-2_PTP::M96HD01-MUE01-U32_0:TPE_0-1-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": 0.0,
      "Route": [
        "5c94b48a-af6c-4c24-8e91-5dea4918d48d",
        "5c94b48b-12ce-4aef-bf4f-f538477418ec"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 33,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 27.5,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1533.07
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 76,
      "FEC_Type": "",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "9-1-lab-A-OSN6800_1:TPE_1-11-3_PTP::9-9-C-OSN6800_1:TPE_1-11-3_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 8,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 6.666666666666667,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1558.98
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": null,
      "FEC_Type": "",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "9-7-B-OSN6800_3:TPE_3-1-1_PTP::9-9-C-OSN6800_3:TPE_3-1-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": null
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 30,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "M96HD01-MUE01-U32_0:TPE_0-8-1_PTP::M96HD01-A2E01-U32_0:TPE_0-8-1_PTP",
      "Latency": 0.0,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": 0.000323,
      "Route": [
        "5c94b488-95e5-4f83-8dad-deffcee3a027",
        "5c94b489-86a2-444a-85d7-e54a8d7c68fd"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 25,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 20.833333333333336,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 1540.56
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 85,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE4/130SNX10-2-15-L1-1 NODE6/130SNX10-2-13-L1-1 ODU4 OTU4#1 ODU4:1",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a6-5cd7-449f-a85f-0beae3bd24dc",
        "5c94c5a5-85a7-4c41-8ca5-7b986a803c7c"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 32,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 26.666666666666668,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 10
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 69,
      "FEC_Type": "EFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE1-PSS4/11DPM12-2-7-L1-1 NODE2-PSS4/11DPM12-2-7-L2-1 _296:1",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-057c-4cbe-a36e-aa31502d3dca",
        "5c94c5a5-27ca-4ddf-9996-dc203d92f611"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 0
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 87,
      "FEC_Type": "EFEC2",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE4/11STMM10-2-14-L1 NODE6/11STMM10-2-7-L1 OTU2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a6-5cd7-449f-a85f-0beae3bd24dc",
        "5c94c5a5-85a7-4c41-8ca5-7b986a803c7c"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 4,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 3.3333333333333335,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 10
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 52,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC-G2",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE5/OTU-1-9-L1 NODE7/OTU-1-9-L1 OTU4",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-b1c0-46df-b739-6bbc6cb519da",
        "5c94c5a6-3fb7-464a-a564-c356af83e996",
        "5c94c5a5-7a63-4d0c-93fc-13c89aef1e5a",
        "5c94c5a5-518b-4fa3-9c2b-153f2b92d109",
        "5c94c5a5-1cba-4147-950f-2a01c5b43319",
        "5c94c5a5-2911-4961-8fd1-2ff10e44a344"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 8,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 6.666666666666667,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 160
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 43,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE5#OCS/OTUODU4-1-1-17-1 NODE6#OCS/OTUODU4-1-1-7-1 ODU4",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a6-8ca8-4501-8fc2-85b801c5eab7",
        "5c94c5a5-bf60-47dd-a65a-b1421c0e5bad",
        "5c94c5a5-1cba-4147-950f-2a01c5b43319",
        "5c94c5a5-2911-4961-8fd1-2ff10e44a344"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 24,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 20.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 160
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 75,
      "FEC_Type": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE5/OCH-2-6-1 NODE7/OCH-2-6-1 OTU4X2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-1cba-4147-950f-2a01c5b43319",
        "5c94c5a5-2911-4961-8fd1-2ff10e44a344"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 160
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 51,
      "FEC_Type": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE7/OCH-2-6-2 NODE5/OCH-2-6-2 OTU4X2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-1cba-4147-950f-2a01c5b43319",
        "5c94c5a5-2911-4961-8fd1-2ff10e44a344"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 160
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 69,
      "FEC_Type": "EFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE1-PSS4/11DPM12-2-7-L2-1 NODE3-PSS4/11DPM12-2-7-L1-1 _311:1",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-bb69-451e-9162-82bcda094493",
        "5c94c5a5-d268-413a-bd02-af497640c390"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 0
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 41,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC-G2",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE4/OCH-2-11-L1 NODE6/OCH-2-8-L1 OTU4X2 ODU4:1 ODU4#2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-b1c0-46df-b739-6bbc6cb519da",
        "5c94c5a6-3fb7-464a-a564-c356af83e996",
        "5c94c5a5-7a63-4d0c-93fc-13c89aef1e5a",
        "5c94c5a5-518b-4fa3-9c2b-153f2b92d109",
        "5c94c5a6-8ca8-4501-8fc2-85b801c5eab7",
        "5c94c5a5-bf60-47dd-a65a-b1421c0e5bad",
        "5c94c5a5-3e64-480b-b512-54f0ed736abe",
        "5c94c5a5-2807-488a-b354-b88c7b12f106"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 10
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 67,
      "FEC_Type": "EFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE1-PSS4/11DPM12-2-8-L1-1 NODE2-PSS4/11DPM12-2-8-L2-1 _299:2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-057c-4cbe-a36e-aa31502d3dca",
        "5c94c5a5-27ca-4ddf-9996-dc203d92f611"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 0
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 50,
      "FEC_Type": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE7/OCH-2-10-2 NODE5/OCH-2-10-2 OTU4X2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-b1c0-46df-b739-6bbc6cb519da",
        "5c94c5a6-3fb7-464a-a564-c356af83e996",
        "5c94c5a5-7a63-4d0c-93fc-13c89aef1e5a",
        "5c94c5a5-518b-4fa3-9c2b-153f2b92d109"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 10
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 69,
      "FEC_Type": "EFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE2-PSS4/11DPM12-2-7-L1-1 NODE3-PSS4/11DPM12-2-7-L2-1 _305:1",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-4d87-4d69-bdcd-521a36a245f4",
        "5c94c5a5-9c57-4404-99b1-de339f22bea3"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 0
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 39,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE4/OCH-1-11-L1 NODE6/OCH-1-11-L1 OTU4X2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-b1c0-46df-b739-6bbc6cb519da",
        "5c94c5a6-3fb7-464a-a564-c356af83e996",
        "5c94c5a5-3e64-480b-b512-54f0ed736abe",
        "5c94c5a5-2807-488a-b354-b88c7b12f106",
        "5c94c5a6-5cd7-449f-a85f-0beae3bd24dc",
        "5c94c5a5-85a7-4c41-8ca5-7b986a803c7c"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 20
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 50,
      "FEC_Type": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE7/OCH-2-10-1 NODE5/OCH-2-10-1 OTU4X2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a6-8ca8-4501-8fc2-85b801c5eab7",
        "5c94c5a5-bf60-47dd-a65a-b1421c0e5bad",
        "5c94c5a5-3e64-480b-b512-54f0ed736abe",
        "5c94c5a5-2807-488a-b354-b88c7b12f106"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 40,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 33.333333333333336,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 10
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 67,
      "FEC_Type": "EFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE2-PSS4/11DPM12-2-8-L1-1 NODE3-PSS4/11DPM12-2-8-L2-1 _302:2",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-4d87-4d69-bdcd-521a36a245f4",
        "5c94c5a5-9c57-4404-99b1-de339f22bea3"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 0
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 43,
      "FEC_Type": "SDFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "NODE5#OCS/OTUODU4-1-1-7-1 NODE6#OCS/OTUODU4-1-1-17-1 ODU4",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-3e64-480b-b512-54f0ed736abe",
        "5c94c5a5-2807-488a-b354-b88c7b12f106"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 8,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 6.666666666666667,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 10
    },
    {
      "Central_Frequency_Division": "?",
      "Channel_Capacity_Gbps": null,
      "Channel_Capacity_ODU": null,
      "Channel_Number": 67,
      "FEC_Type": "EFEC",
      "Free_Bandwidth_Gbps": null,
      "Free_Bandwidth_ODU": null,
      "Label": "Test_SA_CWDM",
      "Latency": null,
      "OSNR": null,
      "OSNR_Threshold": null,
      "Pre_FEC_BER": null,
      "Route": [
        "5c94c5a5-bb69-451e-9162-82bcda094493",
        "5c94c5a5-d268-413a-bd02-af497640c390"
      ],
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_Gbps": 0,
      "Utilized_Bandwidth_ODU": 0.0,
      "Wavelength_Distance": 0
    }
  ],
  "Meta": {
    "limit": 100,
    "offset": 0,
    "records": 30,
    "total": 30
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically set the content of your cells, you need to work with the props `Cell` for each column.
In your case, you want to change the cell content of the column `Route`. To show the corresponding Routes of your cell, do like this :

```
{
  Header: "Route",
  accessor: "Route",
  Cell: row =>
    row.row.original.Route.map(route => (
       <ul>
         <li>{route}</li>
       </ul>
    )),
  id: "Route",
  width: 200
}
```

This renders a bulleted list of the corresponding Routes of your row.